# "createDecipheriv is not implemented yet we accept pull requests" using webpack, react and iron

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

In the process of setting up a project that uses webpack and react.

I'm using Iron to unseal a SID stored in my cookies

```
Iron.unseal(sid, 'secret', Iron.defaults, function (err, authenticatedUser) {
    ...
});
```

but getting this error when I do

> Uncaught Error: sorry, createDecipheriv is not implemented yet we accept pull requests

My current JSON package is:

```
{
  "name": "webpack-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "TARGET=dev webpack-dev-server",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^5.8.22",
    "babel-loader": "^5.3.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.16.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "node-libs-browser": "^0.5.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.12.3",
    "webpack": "^1.11.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.10.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.1.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "iron": "^2.1.3",
    "react": "^0.13.3"
  }
}
```